# Improvement of average word length algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I code calculating the average word length. I wrote a simple example with getting text from lorem ipsum API. When number of paragraphs is 10<sup>5</sup>, the algorithm is going in acceptable time. But if I change amount of paragraphs to 10<sup>6</sup>, it is dying. Here's my code:

```py
import re
import requests

paragraphs = 10**5

# Getting 100 lorem ipsum paragraphs (limit is 100)
x = '\n'.join(requests.get(f'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras={100}').json())

# multiplying if needed (go get expected number of paragraphs)
x = '\n'.join([x for _ in range(paragraphs // 100)]) 
print("Paragraphs: " + str(len(x.split('\n'))))

# start of calculating
print("Calculating...")
x = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]').sub('', x)
print(sum([len(i) for i in x.split()]) / len(x.split()))
```

Let's say that my algorithm will have to calculate even more than a million paragraphs of text and I want it to go fast. So here's questions:

**Is there any way to speed up this code I wrote?**

**If no, in which language would it work in sane amount of time?**

Comment: What do you mean by "it is dieing"? What happens exactly?

Comment: The amount of time in which this algorithm executes is huge

Comment: Like few seconds or even more, that's not acceptable

Comment: The first step is to find out where the program is taking the most time. Are you certain it is in the calculation? Or does the request also take a long time?

Comment: That's why I  do `print("Calculating...")` because then I know where the computer starts calculations. And yeah, after `print("Calculating...")` the code stops for long. That's definitely not a request issue

Comment: Ok. I have two suggestions below. Both of these will only improve the constant factor. I don't think you can do any better than linear time here, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are several places you can optimize this code:

1. You do `x = '\n'.join()` then immediately `x.split('\n')`. Find a way to remove this redundancy.
2. You have a linear operation to remove all non-alphabetic characters or spaces from your input. Then you have another linear operation with `x.split()` (and you call this twice!). You can improve by a constant factor here by writing your own for loop.

Comment: I have noticed that this code takes a lot of memory as well. Maybe there is something that  I can improve with memory access or something along this lines

Comment: @pypy11 The `'\n'.join()` builds a very large string in memory. And each time creates a new copy while doing the `join()`. And then you create a new array in memory with `x.split()`. So find a different way by iterating over the data from the response directly.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [Code-Apprentice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087106/3789665)

> 1. You do x = '\n'.join() then immediately x.split('\n'). Find a way to remove this redundancy.

> 2. You have a linear operation to remove all non-alphabetic characters or spaces from your input. Then you have another linear operation with x.split() (and you call this twice!). You can improve by a constant factor here by writing your own for loop.

I fixed your code as I could.

You are doing many "large" steps on the big object. I change your code a bit and I think it runs a bit faster than before. What's more, it uses a lot less memory than before.

**Code**

```py
import re
import requests

PARAGRAPHS = 10**6

x = ' '.join(requests.get(f'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras={100}').json())
x = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]').sub('', x)
x = x.split()
y = []
for _ in range(PARAGRAPHS // 100):
    y.extend(x)

print("Calculating...")
print(sum([len(i) for i in y]) / len(y))
```

If you want to have more trustful difference between my code and yours, you can test it out for example with `datetime.timestamp()` in Python.

## EDIT

I checked [labroid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68090373/13574070) and on my CPU the fastest algorithm runs about `4.5` seconds. I checked how fast runs my solution as well. Here's code with the test:

```py
import re
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def ts():
    return datetime.now().timestamp()

def diff(st, en):
    print(f'{round((en - st) * 1000, 3)} ms')

PARAGRAPHS = 10**6

x = ' '.join(requests.get(f'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras={100}').json())

st = ts()

x = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]').sub('', x)
x = x.split()
y = []
for _ in range(PARAGRAPHS // 100):
    y.extend(x)

result = sum([len(i) for i in y]) / len(y)
en = ts()

print(f'Average: {result}')
print('Time: ', end='')
diff(st, en)
```

It runs about ~3 seconds. If you connect this two answers, you could achieve even a faster method, especially using this method he or she mentioned:

> Use translate instead of regular expression

So good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This speeds things up ~3x by eliminating the regular expression, counting characters instead of summing word lengths, and getting rid of `split` and `join`, all expensive operations. Here's your original code augmented with two other approaches and the results:

```
import re
import requests
import time

paragraphs = 10**6

# Getting 100 lorem ipsum paragraphs (limit is 100)
x = '\n'.join(requests.get(f'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras={100}').json())

# multiplying if needed (go get expectd number of parapgrahps)
x = '\n'.join([x for _ in range(paragraphs // 100)])
print("Paragraphs: " + str(len(x.split('\n'))))

# start of calculating
start = time.time()
print("Original...")
y = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]').sub('', x)
print(f"Average: {sum([len(i) for i in y.split()]) / len(y.split())}")
print(f"Elapsed time: {time.time() - start}\n")

print("Count chars in aggregate...")
start = time.time()
y = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]').sub('', x).split()
print(f"Average: {len(''.join(y)) / len(y)}")
print(f"Elapsed time: {time.time() - start}\n")

print("Use translate instead of regular expression, eliminate split and join...")
start = time.time()
delchars = ''.join((c for c in map(chr, range(256)) if not c.isalpha())).replace(' ', '')
table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(delchars))
y = x.translate(table)
# Remove multiple spaces
z = y
oldlen = 0
while True:
    z = z.replace('  ', ' ')
    if oldlen == len(z):
        break
    oldlen = len(z)
spaces = z.count(" ")
print(f"Average: {(len(z) - spaces - 1) / spaces}")
print(f"Elapsed time: {time.time() - start}")
```

with the following results (on a Mac mini M1):

```
Paragraphs: 1000000
Original...
Average: 6.029508616708387
Elapsed time: 24.557698965072632

Count chars in aggregate...
Average: 6.029508616708387
Elapsed time: 20.637866020202637

Use translate instead of regular expression...
Average: 6.029508695652174
Elapsed time: 8.14932894706726
```

So it is a little faster to count chars instead of sum words, saving about 5% in time. I show this because it produces *exactly* the same average word length. If, however, you want speed, it is faster to use `translate`, though the answer is *very slightly* different (arising from issues like "do you count hyphens in the length of a hyphenated word?". It turns out the rules for how `split()` works are not well documented that I can find, and how it eliminates/counts hyphens and apostrophes or grave accent changes the answer very slightly. You can tune this as you'd like by removing things you want to count from the `delchars` string.

As for memory and memory-related crashes/slowing: You will need to chunk your incoming data, or source it within your code using a generator. These may also help with speed (depending on if your machine is using memory swap space, for example).